# Tkinter app using selenium not responding after clicking run

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, user-interface, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver

I created an instagram bot that uses the selenium webdriver along with a tkinter interface. However when the browser is running, the app does not respond not allowing to close it midway or anything else. The tkinter app runs in a seperate class to the actual code

```
import tkinter as tk
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import threading
import random
import sys
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import * 
from time import strftime 
from tkinter import messagebox
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException



# THIS VERSION IS V 1.1.0
# THIS UPDATE INCLUDES THE NEW LAYOUT FOR THE GUI USING TTKINTER
# NEW MENUS ARE INCLUDED IN THIS UPDATE
# ADDED NUMBER OF PICTURES TO LIKE OPTION
# NEW FORMAT 
# FIXED BUGS EXCLUDING RANDOM REDIRECTION ISSUE 
# Note: This works with Chromedriver V77 and Chrome V77

class StartPage(tk.Tk):

    # Load application
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("Instagram Bot - Created By HudZah")

        # Creating menubar
        menubar = Menu(root)

        print("Application loading, please wait")
        print("When you install this application, you agree to the abide by the Terms And Conditions stated in the installtion folder. This software is not intended to be used for the exploitation of Instagram, rather as a means of promoting your product. Any detention or suspension that is resulted due to excessive use of this Bot is in no means the fault of the publisher, but the consequences faced by the user. It should be clear that this Bot should not be misused or overused, this might result in unknown penalties to be faced by the user." + "\n Created by HudZah") 

        Border = 3

        canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=700)
        canvas.pack()

        MainFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
        MainFrame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        # Adding file menu and commands
        file = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = file)
        file.add_command(label ='New File', command = None) 
        file.add_command(label ='Run', command = lambda:GetUserInfo(Username.get(), Password.get(), List.get())) 
        file.add_command(label ='Save', command = None) 
        file.add_separator() 
        file.add_command(label ='Exit', command = root.destroy) 

        # Adding Edit Menu and commands 
        edit = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0) 
        menubar.add_cascade(label ='Edit', menu = edit) 
        edit.add_command(label ='Cut', command = None) 
        edit.add_command(label ='Copy', command = None) 
        edit.add_command(label ='Paste', command = None) 
        edit.add_command(label ='Select All', command = None) 
        edit.add_separator() 
        edit.add_command(label ='Find...', command = None) 
        edit.add_command(label ='Find again', command = None) 

        # Adding Help Menu 
        help_ = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0) 
        menubar.add_cascade(label ='Help', menu = help_) 
        help_.add_command(label ='Help', command = None) 
        help_.add_command(label ='Tutorials', command = None) 
        help_.add_separator() 
        help_.add_command(label ='About BOTIG', command = None) 
        UsernameFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg="lightgrey", bd=Border)
        help_.add_command(label ='Information', command = None) 


        # Relative width to the canvas
        UsernameFrame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.135, relwidth=0.60,
                            relheight=0.1, anchor="n")

        Username = tk.Entry(UsernameFrame, font=40)
        Username.insert(0, "Username")
        Username.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        Username.focus()
        PasswordFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg="lightgrey", bd=Border)
        PasswordFrame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.26, relwidth=0.60,
                            relheight=0.1, anchor="n")

        Password = tk.Entry(PasswordFrame, show="*",  font=40)
        Password.insert(0, "Password")
        Password.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        ListFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg="lightgrey", bd=Border)

        ListFrame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.385, relwidth=0.60,
                        relheight=0.1, anchor="n")
        List = tk.Entry(ListFrame, font=40)
        List.insert(0, "Explore Hashtags, eg: food, nyc")
        List.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        # Minutes
        PicsInput = Spinbox(root, from_= 1, to = 2000, font = 13)
        PicsInput.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.61, relwidth=0.14,
                     relheight=0.055, anchor = "n")

        button = tk.Button(MainFrame, text="Run",
                           command=lambda:GetUserInfo(Username.get(), Password.get(), List.get(), PicsInput.get()))

        button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.71, relwidth=0.25,
                     relheight=0.085, anchor="n")

        button = tk.Button(MainFrame, text="Quit",
                           command= root.destroy)

        button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.81, relwidth=0.25,
                     relheight=0.085, anchor="n")

        label = tk.Label(root, text = "Created by HudZah © 2019", font = 13, bg = "white", fg = "black")
        label.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.93, anchor = "n")

        PicsInputLabel = tk.Label(root, text = "Pictures Per Hashtag", font = 7, bg = "white", fg = "black")
        PicsInputLabel.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.55, relwidth = 0.3, anchor = "n")

        # Create label to show errors to users and Info of bot when closed
        root.config(menu = menubar) 

    #pyinstaller --add-binary="Documents/chromedriver.exe;." InstagramBotV1.1.0.py
class InstagramBot(tk.Tk):
    # Run page
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(2)
        LoginButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//a[@href='/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher']")
        LoginButton.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        UsernameElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//input[@name='username']")
        UsernameElem.clear()
        UsernameElem.send_keys(self.username)
        PasswordElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//input[@name='password']")
        PasswordElem.clear()
        PasswordElem.send_keys(self.password)
        PasswordElem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(6)

    def LikePhoto(self, hashtag, NumOfPics, pages):

        driver = self.driver 
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + hashtag + "/")
        time.sleep(3)
        # gathering photos
        PicLinks = []

        print("Check : Number of pages are", pages)
        for i in range(0,pages):
            try:
                driver.execute_script(
                    "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                time.sleep(2)
                # get tags
                Links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
                # finding relevant hrefs

                Links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in Links
                        if ".com/p/" in elem.get_attribute("href")]
                for i in range (0,len(Links)):
                    if Links[i] not in PicLinks:
                        PicLinks.append(Links[i])

                print(
                    "Check: Total N.of pic hrefs stored after array : " + str(len(PicLinks)) + " , in " + hashtag)
                # print(Links)
            except Exception:
                continue

        LikedPhotos = 0
        for i in range(0, len(PicLinks)):
            print("Num" , i , " : " ,  PicLinks[i])
        # Liking photos
        UniquePhotos = int(NumOfPics)
        #for PicLinks in Links:
        for i in range(0,int(NumOfPics)):
            driver.get(PicLinks[i])
            time.sleep(4)
            driver.execute_script(
                "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            try:
                time.sleep(random.randint(5, 9))

                #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//class[@glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7]").click()
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@aria-label="Like"]').click()  # Anonymous function

                time.sleep(1)
                UniquePhotos = UniquePhotos - 1
                LikedPhotos = LikedPhotos + 1
                print("Picture liked : ",LikedPhotos , " Pictures left : ", UniquePhotos)

            except Exception:
                time.sleep(2)

    def closeBrowser(self):
        self.driver.close()
        print("Browser quit")
# Pass info to main class


def GetUserInfo(username, password, hashtagReceived, nOfPics):
    if password and username and hashtagReceived:
        if username != "Username" and password != "Password" and hashtagReceived != "Explore Hashtags, eg: food, nyc":
            try:
                if int(nOfPics) != 0:
                    if messagebox.askokcancel('Application','Application is running, press OK to continue') == True:
                        hashtags = []
                        username = username
                        password = password
                        pages = int(nOfPics)/10
                        pages = int(pages)
                        if pages < 1:
                            pages = 1
                        else:
                            pages = pages
                        #print("username is ", username, "ands password is", password)
                        # Split hashtags into an array
                        hashtags = hashtagReceived.split(",")
                        try:
                            print(hashtags)
                            IG = InstagramBot(username, password)
                            IG.login()
                            i = 0

                        except:
                            messagebox.showerror("Could not execute task. Please try again.")

                        try:
                            while i <= len(hashtags):
                            # Choose a random tag from the list of tags
                                tag = hashtags[i]
                                tag = tag.replace(" ", "")
                                IG.LikePhoto(tag, nOfPics, pages)
                                i = i + 1
                        except ValueError:
                            print("Value could not be converted to an integer.")

                        except Exception:
                            if i != len(hashtags):
                                IG.closeBrowser()
                                print("Browser crashed")
                                time.sleep(3)
                                IG = InstagramBot(username, password)
                                IG.login()
                                i = 0
                            elif i == len(hashtags):
                                print("Hashtags are out")

                        finally:
                            print("Program finished")
                            IG.closeBrowser()




                    else:
                        SystemExit()
                else:
                    messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please enter a valid number of posts to like")
                    print("Please enter a valid number of posts to like")
            except Exception:
                messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please enter a valid number of posts to like")
                print("Please enter a valid number of posts to like")                

        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please enter suitable data")
            print("Please enter suitable data")
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning('Error', 'Please enter a username or password')  #shows warning message
        print("Please enter a username and password")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Run from main")
    root = tk.Tk()
    Start = StartPage(root)
    root.mainloop()
else:
    print("Run from import")
```

The browser runs perfectly fine and the code works. However if you try and click any buttons on the app, it does not respond. It is supposed to run the browser as well as run the app simultaneously

Comment: "The tkinter app runs in a seperate class to the actual code" - how exactly are you starting up both this tkinter app and the code that runs the Selenium stuff?

Comment: Calling the application gui code first. Once details are entered and hit run, the selenium class runs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because selenium and tkinter are running on the same thread/process, you need either use the threading module or subprocess module to run it, doing this your tkinter application will not be freezing anymore.

Threading documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Subprocess documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

You can find some implementations of threading [on this link](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

Comment: How do I implement threading in my case? I went through the documents and several videos and have understood how to use it. But I don't understand how to use it in my case. I tried to do it and the program runs fine, however the application still does not respond

Comment: For my case, when i faced this issue, i've solved doing exactly this:

1 - All the actions did by buttons(command option) i transformed in functions.

2 - To comunicate the variables on each Thread, i've used global variables.

3 - Every time i needed to invoke a function with the button click, i was invoking a function that has a the invoke to the thread module inside it, so, it was a function that calls the thread module and starts to do what the button click shall performe

Comment: How would that stop the app from not responding? Does the threat inside the module with the variables run the main program itself?

Comment: We had very different implementation, you can see mine here 

https://github.com/xhenrique/Tkinter-SmartQuadro-Hexa/blob/testbranch/ttkiner.py

Comment: The threading spawning line will not hang your code, the thread module will execute your function and the function which called the thread module will end normally, this is why you don't get blocked in the main window

Comment: This seems like a lot of work and time to invest in. I already tried to implement the threading and yet does not work even after I create seperate threads. Should I consider using something other than Tkinter? Such as PyQT

Comment: I also dont see a problem with my code? It should work, the gui and program run on seperate threads

Comment: I've executed your code, the gui open fine, but i'm not able to test it all because it's missing the function ```GetUserInfo()```.
Also, i don't see your selenium function here anywhere.
Without more information i'm blind, can't help.
I've never used any other gui library besides tkinter, i'm not the right person to tell you if you should change it.

Comment: I have edited and included the whole code, try it now